# How can I move the filename section of the RStudio environment pane to see more of the filename?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have some long filenames for my data frames. I would like to be able to see the entire filename in the "Environment" pane in RStudio. It does not matter how much I widen RStudio, the filename is still truncated. I just get more blank space between the summary of the data frame and the tick boxes on the right. The "Files" window is fine, as is the "Git" window.

I have looked at Global Options and there doesn't appear to be a within-frame width option. I have also searched on this site (search terms: "[rstudio] environment" and "[rstudio] environment filename" - the second was due to the first returning almost 2K results). No relevant suggestions of questions appeared while I was typing this one out.

Is it possible to do this in RStudio? If so, how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The [tag:environment] tag and the term in general is going to be heavily confounded with the notion of a "namespace" in R, where an environment _there_ is a collection of named objects (possibly nested, etc). I think this is more likely to get focused help within the [RStudio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/); not saying you can't get something here. Good luck!

Comment: if you hover around the sections, you'll be able to extend the size of environment section or expand the data column within environment for names to be shown

Comment: I've been hovering over each filename, which has been tedious. Ah, I found the width (I work in dark mode and these can be difficult to see). Is there any way of making this permanent rather than having to widen each session? Argh, every time I load a new data frame it resets.

Comment: I don't think so. There is an option under View > Panes > Adjust Center Splitter, but I am not sure if it won't reset next time you open RStudio.

Comment: I'd report "width resetting" after loading a new object as a bug. That is indeed annoying.

Comment: If you could somehow control this `<td class="GNVWDDMDJBC" style="width: 220px;"></td>` and make it to keep the width that you desire, then you'd be fine. But I am not sure how to apply custom styles on RStudio.

Comment: Thanks. I keep thinking that surely, after all this time, I can't be the only person that would like this.

Comment: I don't see this, but I might be looking at the wrong thing.  I can set the name of a dataframe, the name of a column in it, and a value in that column to 100 character strings, and they all adapt to the space available.  Could you include code in your question to create the problematic object?

Comment: The problem is the filenames in the Environment window, not the column names inside a data frame.